# Internet socket behavior when communicating within the same host

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming, posix

I am recently writing some tool for testing some network processes that run across different hosts.

I am tempted to the idea that when testing, instead of running the client and server in different hosts, I can run them within one host.

Since the client and server are using TCP to communicate, so I think this should be fine, except one point below:

**Is the TCP socket behavior the same when communicating data within the same host as the case of across hosts?**

Will the data be physically present to the NIC interface and then routed to the target socket? Or the kernel will bypass the NIC interface under such scenarios?  (Let's limit the OS as only Linux here for discussion)

There seems little specification regarding to such case.

==== EDIT ====

I actually notice some difference between intra-host and inter-host communications.

When doing inter-host communications, my program can successfully get hardware timestamp. But with the exact same code to run within the same host, the hardware timestamp disappears. When supported and enabled, hardware timestamp of TCP packet is available, and is returned as the ancillary data of recvmsg along with the received TCP data. [Linux kernel timestamp doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping.txt) has all the related info.

I checked the source code, the only difference is that whether the sender is within the same host of the receiver, no other difference.

So I am wondering whether Linux kernel will bypass the NIC and present the data directly to the receiver when doing intra-host communication, thus cause the issue.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it's not clear what you mean by "the same". The same in what way? Any two things are different in some way or they would be just one thing. The question is whether the differences matter to you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Check the line below the BOLD one, that's the main points that I would like to know regarding to the behavior. Thanks

Comment: A socket is a socket is a socket, and TCP/IP is TCP/IP is TCP/IP. It doesn't matter where in the world the two peers are, it should work the same if one peer is in Sweden and the other in the Philippines as it would do if both peers are running locally on the same physical computer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The 'should' word is the part I am most concerned about.   It should work exactly the same way as if the socket resides in another host, but I am just not 100% sure of this. Let me add more info in the question.

Comment: Okay, change the "should" to *will*. If it doesn't work the same, then there is a bug in the network stack.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Any ideas of the observed difference I just added then?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "hardware timestamp"? Timestamp *where*? How do you check this timestamp?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It should work the same in the sense that the properties guaranteed by the TCP protocol will be respected in both cases. Other than that, it can work *very* differently.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's what I mean. Same with UDP too of course. All this makes me think the OP have some *other* problem that the OP isn't really telling us about, only hinting to us with the "hardware timestamp" issue.

Comment: To the OP: What is the *actual* problem you have? Why do you need this "hardware timestamp"? What are you actually trying to do or accomplish? Instead of asking about differences, and then in a roundabout say something about these timestamps, why don't you just directly ask about the actual problem you have?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz More info added. This is actually the problem, it's not X/Y problem.   I did some investigation before posting the question.

Comment: There won't be a hardware timestamp for a packet that doesn't traverse any hardware. And in this case, there is no hardware it even *could* traverse because there is no "packet returner" in the system. Most NICs are only capable of returning a packet if put in a test or loopback mode and likely your OS has no capability to do that anyway. (Why would it?)

Answer (score 0):

> Will the data be physically present to the NIC interface and then routed to the target socket?

No. There is typically no device that provides this capability, nor is there any need for one.

> Or the kernel will bypass the NIC interface under such scenarios?

The kernel will not use the NIC unless it needs to send or receive a packet on a network. Typically, NICs can only return local packets if put in a test or loopback mode, which would require them to stop listening to the network.

Comment: I have added more details, any ideas？ According to your post, it shouldn't happen!

Comment: Why would there be a hardware timestamp if no hardware is used?

Comment: The point here is that I specify the same interface to communicate.  So there is difference  here?

Comment: Whatever interface you specify, if it's local traffic, it will use the loopback interface. When you specify the interface, it's used for many things, but it doesn't determine what interface the packet will be transmitted with -- that will be whatever interface gets it to its destination.

Comment: ah, yes, your words remind me of the weak end model of Linux.  Is there any way to specify some socket to use strong end model ? I don't think it's possible, because it's system-wide model. Just wondering.

Comment: @FaceBro That wouldn't work anyway. If the packet were sent on an interface that doesn't connect to the destination, the packet wouldn't get to its destination! Unless you have some kind of "packet returner" connected to that interface, using that interface to send a packet to the local machine won't get the packet to the local machine.